# Translate from Dojo to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I Translate this function to jQuery ?

```
function (parser, connect) {
    dojo.ready(function() {
        parser.parse();
        dojo.style("content", "display", "");
        connect.connect(dijit.byId("myAccountsListItem"), "onClick",
                null, getAccounts);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').css("display", "");

    $('#myAccountsListItem').on('click', getAccounts);
})
```